# jQuery resolution change css

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, resolution

I am bussy with a responive design and i have this js code

```
$("#gradient #wrapper #camboxs .cambox:nth-child(5n)").not("#gradient #wrapper #footer .box #camboxs .combox").css("margin-right","0");
```

I want when somewone resize there brower smaller then 980px or the browser starts on 980px or smaller then the function change to:

```
$("#gradient #wrapper #camboxs .cambox:nth-child(2n)").not("#gradient #wrapper #footer .box #camboxs .combox").css("margin-right","0");
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Example code: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css

Comment: Your selectors are really convoluted and overly verbose. Why don't you just use $('#camboxs .cambox:nth-child(5n)'). IDs are unique so it doesnt make a difference other than making it faster.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using javascript for this? Can be done with pure css:

```
#gradient #wrapper #camboxs .cambox:nth-child(5n):not(#gradient #wrapper #footer .box #camboxs .combox)
{
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

And then use media queries:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 980px), projection and (max-width: 980px)
{
    /* first undo the general styles */
    #gradient #wrapper #camboxs .cambox:nth-child(5n):not(#gradient #wrapper #footer .box #camboxs .combox)
    {
        margin-right: 10px; /* replace with the original margin */
    }
    #gradient #wrapper #camboxs .cambox:nth-child(2n):not(#gradient #wrapper #footer .box #camboxs .combox)
    {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

Like Andy suggested, it could be done with way less code.

And for the fallback: To react on window resize, use the following with jQuery (untested):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 980) {
        $("#gradient #wrapper #camboxs .cambox:nth-child(5n)").not("#gradient #wrapper #footer .box #camboxs .combox").css("margin-right","");
        $("#gradient #wrapper #camboxs .cambox:nth-child(2n)").not("#gradient #wrapper #footer .box #camboxs .combox").css("margin-right","0");
    } else {
        $("#gradient #wrapper #camboxs .cambox:nth-child(2n)").not("#gradient #wrapper #footer .box #camboxs .combox").css("margin-right","");
        $("#gradient #wrapper #camboxs .cambox:nth-child(5n)").not("#gradient #wrapper #footer .box #camboxs .combox").css("margin-right","0");
    }
});
```

Comment: @Maanstraat, I see. That's true of course. Media queries are not compatible too by the way. But maybe you could use this and have some fallback for IE. Just my opinion: Whenever you can do something without js, do it. ;-)

Comment: @Maanstraat, I made an update. But the code is untested, so please correct me, if it's buggy.

Comment: Hi Linus, thnx. but this only works when you resize it not when it starts on the resoluitons...

Comment: @Maanstraat, I'm not sure, but I think it should be enough to just call `$(window).resize()` without parameters on page load.

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly advise using media queries and css3 selectors and then using a shim or polyfill. We shouldn't sacrifice code quality and performance for the sake of a 10+ year old browser.

So, here's a media query emulator for IE7/8:

http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.0%28beta3%29/IE8.js

and here's a css3 polyfill for IE6/7/8:

http://selectivizr.com/

Have fun!

Comment: Hi, This is working well for everyting but when i start or resize the browser in IE 8 then it's not change to the mobile layout. (Chrome and all other works fine) Do you know how i can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 980px)  {
    /* Styles */

    $("#gradient #wrapper #camboxs .cambox:nth-child(2n)").not("#gradient #wrapper #footer .box #camboxs .combox").css("margin-right","0");
}
```